# Magento 2 : How to filter customer group collection?

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, customer-group

Anybody have idea about how can i filter customer group pragmatically ?

I can able to get customer group collection by using below code.

```
$customerGroupsCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection');

print_r($customerGroupsCollection->getData()); exit;
```

**Output**

```
[6] => Array
    (
        [customer_group_id] => 9
        [customer_group_code] => first
        [tax_class_id] => 3
        [custom_shipping_amount] => 1200
        [group_creator] => newnew
        [group_creator_id] => 10
        [group_code] => first
        [total_members] => 
        [group_validity] => 
        [members_name] => 
        [member_profile_image] => 
        [group_shopping_amount] => 
        [group_image] => /k/o/koala_1.jpg
        [group_link] => first
    )
```

Now i am trying to apply **addAttributeToFilter** but its not working !?

Anyone know what is missing ?

```
$customerGroupsCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection');

$customerGroupsCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('group_link',['eq'=>'thisisfreshgroup']);
print_r($customerGroupsCollection->getData()); exit;
```

Getting unDefined Method **addAttributeToFilter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    $customerGroupsCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection');

    $customerGroupsCollection->addFieldToFilter('group_link',['eq'=>'thisisfreshgroup']);

    $collection = $customerGroupsCollection->getData();

    foreach ($collection as $value) {
       $customer_group_id[] = $value['customer_group_id'];
     }
    print_r($customer_group_id);
```

Comment: It's working, I totally forgot about addFieldToFilter(), But i also have to remove addAttributeToSelect to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @LazyCoder please accept the answer, this is working for you and this will helpful for others

Comment: I'm unable to get customer group Id, I try with echo $customerGroupsCollection->getCustomerGroupId();

Comment: What error coming?

Comment: Call to undefined method  Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection::getCustomerGroupId();

Comment: @LazyCoder please check my updated answer

Comment: @LazyCoder Is  that working means please accept the answer

Comment: I know this stuff. I want to get by using Magent's magic method.BTW thanks for your time. Will give you upvote for actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

One should use dependency injection and refrain from using objectManager directly.

First inject customer collection factory to constructor :

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory 
){
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Then add a method to retrieve collection :

```php
public function getFreshCustomers(){
    $customerCollection = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $customerCollection->addFieldToFilter('group_id',6);
    return $customerCollection;
}
```

Where 6 is the group id one is looking for.